# In GNU/Linux, how do I use mingw-w64 with SCons to produce a 64-bit Windows executable?

Tags: linux, gnu, scons, mingw-w64, win64

I'm using Linux Mint.

How can I use mingw-w64 with SCons to produce a 64-bit Windows executable? I'm using:

```
Environment(tools = ['mingw'], ...)
```

but it seems to use `g++` anyway.

Comment: Does [this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898584/how-can-i-use-a-cross-compiler-with-scons)?

Comment: Or this may help. http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/base.html . Hm.. I see the link says mingw32, there is also info on mingw-w64 there. Good luck.

Comment: @Petesh: I think it does, but why doesn't `tools = ['mingw']` work? Why do I have to specify all tools with `env_options`?

Comment: @shellter: I think that's for Windows.

Comment: I think it only specifies the general toolchain model, and as you're not running on Windows falls back to defaults on Linux. Cross compilation would not be the default behavior in any case.

Comment: I've never seen mention of running mingw under linux only windows, but I've never had to dig in a cross-compile. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using fedora 23, but I see the same behavior there that you describe, and here is a solution...  Once you specify the mingw tool, it will setup the environment correctly with extensions and such, but you may have to tell it where your compiler and linker are.  I'm sure it's different on every distribution...

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.6.rel_2.3.5:3347:d31d5a4e74b6[MODIFIED], 2015/07/31 14:36:10, by bdbaddog on hpmicrodog
    engine: v2.3.6.rel_2.3.5:3347:d31d5a4e74b6[MODIFIED], 2015/07/31 14:36:10, by bdbaddog on hpmicrodog
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2015 The SCons Foundation

>> tree  
.
├── main.cpp
└── SConstruct

0 directories, 2 files

>> cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }

>> cat SConstruct 
env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'])
env.Replace(CXX='/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++',
            LINK='/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++')
env.Program('main.cpp')

>> scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.exe main.o
scons: done building targets.

>> tree
.
├── main.cpp
├── main.exe
├── main.o
└── SConstruct

0 directories, 4 files

>> file main.exe
main.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```