# How do I use a non-gnu compiler with SCons?

Tags: cross-compiling, scons

I'm developing some code for a digital signal processing card that uses a language called 'Cn' - very similar to C, with a few important differences like the introduction of 'mono' and 'poly' variables.

The compiler is called 'cscn', and is located at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\clearspeed\bin\cscn.exe' (it's a Windows host system.) I'm investigating the use of SCons to do my compiling and dependency generation, but I can't seem to get SCons to recognize/use the cscn compiler. A very simple compilation command should be

```
cscn pi.cn -lcn_reduction -o pi.csx
```

My most recent attempt at a configuration script is

```
env = Environment()
env.Replace(CC = ['C:\Program Files (x86)\clearspeed\bin\cscn.exe'])
env.Program('pi.csx', 'pi.cn', CFLAGS='-lcn_reduction')
```

What I get, however, is an error message telling me that 'No version of Visual Studio compiler found' and that I must specify at least one .exe target for my build. cscn doesn't build an .exe file, it builds a .csx file. I was hoping I could replace the compiler it attempts to use with the env.Replace() command, but evidently not.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Aside, unrelated to your question: using backslashes in Python strings will eventually bite you. Prefer `'C:/Prog...'` or `'C:\\Prog...'` or `r'C:\Prog...'`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
env = Environment(CC = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/clearspeed/bin/cscn.exe')
env.Program('pi.csx', 'pi.cn', CFLAGS='-lcn_reduction')
```

instead. The simple `Environment()` call defaults to

```
env = Environment(tools=['default'])
```

which means that SCons tries to find its Tools, like `gcc` or `g++`, first. If you replace their paths afterwards, it will be too late...the corresponding `Builder`s like `Program` and `Library` won't have been initialized for the current environment because no compiler was found.
Note that you may have to replace several other variables (`AR` and `LINK` come to mind) for getting your whole toolchain going properly. See also [How can I use a cross compiler with Scons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898584/how-can-i-use-a-cross-compiler-with-scons) .

If you continue to struggle with this, you might want to come over to our user mailing list at `scons-users@scons.org` (see http://scons.org/lists.html) and ask your further questions there.

Comment: Our answers crossed in the ether.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to make a couple changes.
Firstly, since you are on windows, SCons will default to configuring Visual Studio tools if they are available,

See: [SCons/Tool/**init**.py](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/src/dba71123682329d2a90e9f6269a9647ebb9fc3f1/src/engine/SCons/Tool/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-1004)

```
c_compilers = ['msvc', 'mingw', 'gcc', 'intelc', 'icl', 'icc', 'cc', 'bcc32' ]
```

So first let's fix that:

```
env = Environment(tools=[])
env['CC'] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\clearspeed\bin\cscn.exe'
env.Tool('cc')
env['LINK'] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\clearspeed\bin\cscn.exe'
env.Tool('link')
env.Program('pi.csx', 'pi.cn', CFLAGS='-lcn_reduction')
```

Likely, that's still not enough because SCons doesn't know about .csx and .cn file suffixes. So let's fix that:

```
env = Environment(tools=[])
env['CC'] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\clearspeed\bin\cscn.exe'
env.Tool('cc')
env['LINK'] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\clearspeed\bin\cscn.exe'
env.Tool('link')
env['PROGSUFFIX'] = '.csx'
# Note we removed that from the output for program as it should automatically add it.
env.Program('pi', 'pi.cn', CFLAGS='-lcn_reduction')
```

Next you'll need to tell SCons that .cn's can make object files.

```
import SCons.Tool
import SCons.Default
static_obj, shared_obj = SCons.Tool.createObjBuilders(env)
my_suffix = '.cn'
static_obj.add_action(my_suffix, SCons.Defaults.CAction)
#shared_obj.add_action(my_suffix, SCons.Defaults.ShCAction)
static_obj.add_emitter(my_suffix, SCons.Defaults.StaticObjectEmitter)
#shared_obj.add_emitter(my_suffix, SCons.Defaults.SharedObjectEmitter)
```

That should take care of that.

So let's put it all together:

```
env = Environment(tools=[])
env['CC'] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\clearspeed\bin\cscn.exe'
env.Tool('cc')
env['LINK'] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\clearspeed\bin\cscn.exe'
env.Tool('link')
env['PROGSUFFIX'] = '.csx'

# Add .cn suffix as able to create objects.
import SCons.Tool
import SCons.Default
static_obj, shared_obj = SCons.Tool.createObjBuilders(env)
my_suffix = '.cn'
static_obj.add_action(my_suffix, SCons.Defaults.CAction)
#shared_obj.add_action(my_suffix, SCons.Defaults.ShCAction)
static_obj.add_emitter(my_suffix, SCons.Defaults.StaticObjectEmitter)
#shared_obj.add_emitter(my_suffix, SCons.Defaults.SharedObjectEmitter)

# Note we removed that from the output for program as it should automatically add it.
env.Program('pi', 'pi.cn', CFLAGS='-lcn_reduction')
```

Now, I don't have access to your compiler toolchain, so I've not tried the above, but I believe it should get you most, if not all the way there.

Comment: And if this elaborate approach by @bdbaddog works, please consider wrapping it into a proper "clearspeed" Tool as described in our [Tools for Fools Guide](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools) and then donating it for the [index of external Tools](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsIndex)...

Comment: For sure an actual Tool would be much cleaner way to do this. :)