# Building clingo on windows with scons

Tags: mingw, scons, clingo

I am trying to build clingo with scons. It complains about my compiler set which is "gcc-7-win64" latest version I could find. (I tried it with several older versions)

Error messages:

error: no usable c++ compiler found

error: no usable bison version found

my second question is this: where should I put the libraries that I manually download such as bison for scons to find easly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SCons uses a clean Environment by default (no `PATH` variable set), such that it doesn't find a command/program like "`gcc`" and "`bison`". See also #1 of our most-frequently-asked FAQs at http://scons.org/faq.html.
Please check whether the clingo project has foreseen this problem and offers a command-line option like "`--with-bison`" (or similar) for setting the correct paths within the SConstruct(s).

Additional info: This is not so much a problem under Linux, because there a set of default directories like `/usr/bin` get searched by default when detecting a tool like gcc/yacc/qmake...it can however get one when trying to [cross-compile with SCons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898584/how-can-i-use-a-cross-compiler-with-scons).

Comment: I added these lines to beginning of SConscript file. However I still get the same compiler error.

"import os
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})"

Comment: And I checked "env" with this code "print env.Dump()" my compiler set is in the path.

Comment: Make sure that "`env`" is the actual environment that's used to build/compile stuff. If it is but you see the same error, it's time to contact the project maintainers...the SCons part should be correct, but the project's SConstruct might overwrite settings/variables after that.

Answer (score 0):

Clingo's scons script has a *configure* target. This creates the file build/release.py where you can adjust the paths to all the tools (bison, gcc, re2c) needed. But be warned, I tried to build clingo on windows in the past and had problems finding working bison versions for windows. There are some notes about this in the INSTALL file.