# env.PrependENVPath/AppendENVPath doesnt' work as expected:

Tags: path, environment, scons, prepend

I installed nodejs and hope to add bin directory for scons:

```
import os
env=Environment()
env.PrependENVPath('PATH','/home/my/node/bin')
print "PATH is", env.subst('$PATH')
```

Running scons, it prints:

> PATH is
>   Well no value is printed. Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a cross compiler with Scons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898584/how-can-i-use-a-cross-compiler-with-scons)

Comment: Hint: `env['PATH'] != env['ENV']['PATH']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the following to see the results of your PrependEnvPath

```
import os
env=Environment()
env.PrependENVPath('PATH','/home/my/node/bin')
print("PATH is", env['ENV']['$PATH'])
```

Yields:

```
$ scons.py
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
PATH is:/home/my/node/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```